# c# generic constraint when T is class or primitive type

Tags: c#, generics

Ok , to simplify we have 2 classes:A,B: both clases have a primary key, called key.

```
public class A{
String key;
}

public class B{
int key;
}
```

So we have an interface to manage all entities i called it IRepository, and for this example has only 1 operation:

```
public interface IRepository<T,TKey> where T: class wher Y:class {
    TKey getKey(T entity);
}
```

So when i implement this class and finally resolving the generics, in A case good:

```
public class RepositoryA<A,String> : IRepository<T, TKey>{
 public String getKey(A entity)=> A.key;
}
```

But in B case obviously not, because int is not an object, so i did a class int wrapper:

```
public class RepositoryB<B,IntWrapper> : IRepository<B, IntWrapper>{
public String getKey(B entity)=> B.key;
}
```

Int wrapper just a container of the int value.

```
 public class IntWrapper{
       int value;
    }
```

So the question is: can i indicate something like this???

```
public interface IRepository<T,TKey> where T: class where TKey:class|nonclassvalue
```

Or what is the correct way to do what im doing without tricking IntWrapper?

related with this questions:

[c# where for generic type constraint class may NOT be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65938904/c-sharp-where-for-generic-type-constraint-class-may-not-be)

[c# generic constraint where is not class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551461/c-sharp-generic-constraint-where-is-not-class)

Comment: Just remove the `where TKey: class` constraint from your `IRepository` definition?

Comment: Perfect, answer the question with that

Comment: + i dont think you need `IntWrapper`, was that a hack to get around `where TKey: class`? :)

Comment: The code in your question is incorrect - every snippet which has generics in it has some error which means that it won't compile. Please make sure that you have run the code in your question, and made sure that it reproduces your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So the question is: can i indicate something like this???
>
> `public interface IRepository<T,TKey> where T: class where TKey:class|nonclassvalue`

Sure, just remove the constraint on `TKey` altogether:

```
public interface IRepository<T,TKey> where T: class
```

Comment: Same answer ... +1 for you ;) ... you answered first (in comments). @Author: Accept this :D!

Comment: Note that the original `class` constraint and `nonclassvalue` (which I think is OP's way of saying `struct`?) disallows nullable types. So perhaps `TKey: notnull` is a better constraint?

Answer (score 1):

Just use it without the `TKey` constraint

```cs
public interface IRepository<T,TKey> 
where T: class
```

Without the `TKey:class|nonclassvalue`

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay copy&past :( removed it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public interface IRepository<T, TKey>
{
    TKey getKey(T entity);
}

public class RepositoryA: IRepository<A, string>
{
    public string getKey(A entity) {
      return entity.key;
    }
}

public class RepositoryB: IRepository<B, int>{
  public int getKey(B entity)=> entity.key;
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?