# Can one specity "convertability from int" as a type constraint in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, type-constraints

I have some code that looks like this:

```
class A<T>
      where T : // what should I say here to make this work?
{
   void foo()
   {
      int x = 0;
      T y = (T)x; // this is a compile error without proper type restrictions
   }
}
```

The intent is to use A with types like double, float, int.

Answer (score 3):

You can't have a type constraint for this, unfortunately. However, you can use the [`Convert.ChangeType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtb69x08%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
class A<T>
{
   void foo()
   {
      int x = 0;
      T y = (T)Convert.ChangeType(x, typeof(T));
   }
}
```

This won't stop you from instantiating the class with a type that can't be converted from an `int`, though.

Answer (score 3):

int, float, double  keywords are just syntactic sugar. The compiler maps them to value types like Int32, Float, Double etc (which are structs). Generally you can't force a type T to be a *only* a primitive type but you can impose T to be a value type by doing:

```
class A<T>
  where T : struct
{
   void foo()
   {
      int x = 0;
      T y = (T)Convert.ChangeType(x, typeof(T));  
   }
}
```

Please note that you still need to use Convert.ChangeType as pointed out by Random832. Imposing the type T to be a struct is only to exclude classes (which are not value types). It's not a great advantage but I think it's cleaner.

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805264/how-to-define-generic-type-limit-to-primitive-types) anyway.

hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. If you are gonna use this method with only value types you can specify a `struct` constraint, otherwise you can't restrict `T` to be, float,int,double only.

There is way to get rid of compiler error, you can box the value then cast it back, but it's not a good idea and practice, because this will fail if the type of `x` and `T` are not compatible:

```
T y = (T)(object)x
```

Comment: You can't unbox a float to an int, though.

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest one way to do it(but it's far from being elegant, to be honest):

```
interface IConvertsFromNumeric<T>
{
    T FromLong(long x);
    T FromDouble(double x);
    T FromDecimal(decimal x);
}

class A<T>
  where T : IConvertsFromNumeric<T>, new()
{
   void foo()
   {
      int x = 0;
      T y = new T().FromLong(x);
   }
}
```

Comment: This cannot be made to handle the predefined types, though. You're stuck with the interfaces they implement already, you can't add your own.