# Determine if generic type (where T: struct) has the ability to have maths performed on it?

Tags: c#, generics

I am creating a static class that is used to asynchronously wait for some `T targetValue` to be "approximately" some `T currentValue`. I have already implemented a function to check for exact equality as shown below, but I am having a difficult time with an "approximate value"

```
public delegate T GetValueMethod<T>() where T: struct;

public static Task<Boolean> WaitForExactValueAsync<T>(GetValueMethod<T> getValue, T targetValue, CancellationToken cancelWaitToken, int msTimeout = 10000) where T: struct
{
    return Task.Run<Boolean>(async () =>
    {
        // Create a CancellationToken that times out, then link it with the argument token that requests a the wait to be cancelled
        var timeoutTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(msTimeout));
        var timeoutAndCancelTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(timeoutTokenSource.Token, cancelWaitToken);

        // Continually check to see if we reached the target value or have timed out
        T currentValue = getValue();
        while (!targetValue.Equals(currentValue) && !timeoutAndCancelTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            try { await Task.Delay(500, timeoutAndCancelTokenSource.Token); }catch (Exception ex) { }
            currentValue = getValue();
        }

        // If we got here and the token is not cancelled that means we have reached the target value
        return !timeoutAndCancelTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested;
    });
}
```

The methods I am creating are meant to only work with primitive types such as `int`, `double`, `Boolean`, etc. I do this by implementing [this SO anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/805271/2985796) which describes a way to limit generic types to primitives by forcing the `T` to be a `struct`.

The function above seems to work nicely for my situation because (I think) we can always equate `struct` with `Equals` to determine equality. My issue when creating the approximately equal version is when the type of `T` is something like `Boolean`.

I plan to allow the user to pass in a "closeness" percentage to the function to specify when the two values are "approximately equal" (If the current is within x percentage of the target return true). If `T` is a numeric value I can do this with maths easily, but when its non-numeric it makes no sense to use this method but to simply use `Equals`.

**Is there a way to tell from `T` (`where T : struct`) if I can perform the maths I need to on it (To implement the `IsValueClose` method below)?**

```
private static Boolean ValueIsClose<T>(T target, T value, double percentAsDecimal) 
  where T: struct
{
    // if(value.CanDoTheMaths)
    {
        return Math.Abs((value / target) - target) <= percentAsDecimal;
    }
    // else
    {
        return target.Equals(value);
    }
}
```

**Furthermore once this happens how can I refer to `target` and `value` as a type that can perform these maths?**

From asking somewhat relate questions before I do not think this is quite possible or good practice for generic methods. So from what I can currently tell, my only good solution is to make an "approximate" method for each type I plan to use (the best practice), or to check the `Type` of `T` in `IsValueClose` to see if it is something that I know I can do maths on and go from there (Bad practice for generics).

Though possibly there is a simpler more elegant solution that someone could suggest?

Comment: Use solutions like these http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749966/c-sharp-how-to-determine-whether-a-type-is-a-number to determine whether T is a numeric type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to do this in C#, sadly.

However, Jon Skeet and Marc Gravell have put together a [generic operator framework](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html) that allows to perform operations such as addition, subtraction, multiplication and division on values.