# C# generic type limit to comparable primitive types like int, float, long, etc

Tags: c#, generics

This is sort of a combination of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8982645/how-to-solve-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-t-and-t) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805264/how-to-define-generic-type-limit-to-primitive-types) questions. In the code below, if `T: struct`, then `a==b` cannot be used because structure's cannot be compared. If `T: class`, I cannot pass 1 and 2. If I only want to use comparable primitive value types like `int`, `float`, `enum`, `long`, etc, is there anything other than `T: struct` to limit the type of T?

```
public static bool Test<T>(T a, T b) where T: struct
{
    return a == b;
}

public static async Task Main()
{
    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;
    Test<int>(1, 2);
}
```

Comment: Could you use `a.Equals(b)` instead of `==`?

Comment: How about [`IEqualityOperators`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.iequalityoperators-3?view=net-7.0)?

Comment: ... Or [`IEauqtable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=net-7.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [equals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=net-7.0) for compare types like `int, float, enum, long`

```
public static bool Test<T>(T a, T b) where T: struct
{
   return  a.Equals(b);
}
```